# Stop automatic CMake configure in KDevelop

Tags: c++, cmake, kdevelop

I'm using the latest AppImage of KDevelop (version 5.6.1) on a kubuntu 20.04 to develop and build a project with CMake.

Opposed to earlier versions of KDevelop this one **automatically** executes a CMake configure run whenever I save a source file or a CMake file. Earlier versions only did this on manual request.

This is annoying for me, because I have the reflex to save whenever I stop typing and the CMake configure run switches the tool view to the build panel although I may have been working with another view. Additionally, when I work on my (very complex) CMake configuration I sometimes want to watch the configure run to see some changes in the output.

I went through all global and project-specific settings multiple times, but I couldn't find out how to turn off this behavior, so:

**How can I turn off the automatic execution of CMake on save in KDevelop 5.6.1?**

Comment: I think the automatic configure is a requirement of the new CMake file api. Visual Studio does the same thing. VSCode won't, but I find it usually less accurate.

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Thanks for pointing this out. Looks like this commit introduced the behavior: https://invent.kde.org/kdevelop/kdevelop/commit/893b400bd2c65634c429a071efb25163ea837c3b

Comment: i have this same problem, so it's not possible to turn off?

Comment: @bjhend Have you resolved this trouble?

Comment: @Leon No, but I'm using KDevelop for Python projects now so this does not itch me currently

Comment: @bjhend I found a method can prevent it from auto-config.

in KDevelop's menu:`Settings` -> `Configure KDevelop...` -> `Plugins`
Uncheck "Clang-Tidy Support".

Now, it would not auto-config.

Eventhough you select the plugin again, it would not trigger auto-config after that.

Comment: @Leon Interesting, if you make this an answer I will accept it when it works for me as well.